# Can I use Crystal Report to generate image file (jpg, tiff, png)?

Tags: crystal-reports

Can I use Crystal Report to generate image file (jpg, tiff, png)? I already search google but all tutorials seems to focus on how to integrate image in crystal report.

The idea is to use Crystal Report to generate label image. Then integrate these label image in rpt/pdf files.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Crystal reports supports export to image. You will need to go through an export to one of the supported file formats and then convert it to the desired image format. For example export the report to a PDF and then convert the PDF to an image.